# How to install Intel AVX 2 on Ubuntu

Tags: intel, 20.04, extension

Recently I had a clean intall to Ubuntu 20.04. LTS from Windows 10 and i wanted to install Intel Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (AVX, also known as Sandy Bridge New Extensions). I surfed a lot in the internet and could not find anything for me. but in windows, these extensions were installed automatically. can anyone please help me out to get those?

My Computer info as follows:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           142
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
Stepping:                        10
CPU MHz:                         700.011
CPU max MHz:                     3400.0000
CPU min MHz:                     400.0000
BogoMIPS:                        3600.00
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        1 MiB
L3 cache:                        6 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some highly optimized applications are already using them, but on C/C+ or on Assembly (low-level).

If you want to start programming using this instructions - then you have to install [Intel MKL](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/intel-mkl) packages by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get install libmkl-dev libmkl-avx2
```