# How to enable AVX2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I'm trying to get AVX2 enabled on a machine with Ubuntu 20.04.

I've run these commands to install AVX2:

```
Update the package index:
# sudo apt-get update
Install libmkl-avx2 deb package:
# sudo apt-get install libmkl-avx2
```

as per:

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-multiverse-amd64/libmkl-avx2_2020.0.166-1_amd64.deb.html

The processor is:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : AuthenticAMD
cpu family      : 21
model           : 2
model name      : AMD FX-8320E Eight-Core Processor
stepping        : 0
microcode       : 0x6000852
cpu MHz         : 2036.567
cache size      : 2048 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 16
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc>
bugs            : fxsave_leak sysret_ss_attrs null_seg spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass
bogomips        : 6422.00
TLB size        : 1536 4K pages
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management: ts ttp tm 100mhzsteps hwpstate cpb eff_freq_ro
```

but when checking for avx in cpuinfo I only see avx, not avx2:

```
grep avx /proc/cpuinfo

flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs xop skinit wdt fma4 tce nodeid_msr tbm topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb cpb hw_pstate ssbd ibpb vmmcall bmi1 arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to enable AVX2 somehow?

In case anybody's wondering if I'm asking how to install AVX2. I'm not. They're already installed. Just not available/recognized by the cpu for some reason. see below:

```
root@home:~$ sudo apt-get install libmkl-dev libmkl-avx2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libmkl-avx2 is already the newest version (2020.0.166-1).
libmkl-dev is already the newest version (2020.0.166-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 141 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Intel AVX 2 on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235474/how-to-install-intel-avx-2-on-ubuntu)

Comment: thanks. No it doesn't. libmkl-avx2 and libmkl-dev are already installed. the problem is that they're not enabled/available to run for some reason.

Comment: Looks like your processor doesn't support avx2. See [What do the flags in /proc/cpuinfo mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43539/209257)

Comment: @xiota, thanks! you're right. I just checked the AMD stats for the processor. If you want to write out an answer I'll accept it

Comment: when I run `grep avx /proc/cpuinfo` I see avx2 fma etc. does it mean i dont need to "install" avx2 ?? my ubuntu is 22.04